# Output to Table Variable, Not CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Why is this legal:

```
DECLARE @Party TABLE 
(
  PartyID nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Party
  SELECT Name FROM
  (INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable
     OUTPUT inserted.Name
          VALUES ('hello')) [H]

SELECT * FROM @Party
```

But the next block gives me an error:

```
WITH Hey (Name) 
AS (
  SELECT Name FROM
  (INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable
    OUTPUT inserted.Name
    VALUES ('hello')) [H]
        )

SELECT * FROM Hey
```

The second block gives me the error "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

It seems to be saying thst nested INSERT statements are allowed, but in my CTE case I did not nest inside another INSERT.  I'm surprised at this restriction.  Any work-arounds in my CTE case?

Comment: The error message seems clear to me. It is not allowed to nest the insert statement inside a `SELECT` like that. If it was allowed then what would you expect to happen if you did `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Hey CROSS JOIN SomeOtherTable` It would do 10 inserts?

Comment: Do you have a reason to do this? Or just experimentation?

Comment: As a matter of fact, your (invalid) CTE example is equivalent to just `INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable OUTPUT inserted.Name VALUES ('Hello')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why this is illegal, allowing these `SELECT` operations with side effects would cause all sorts of problems I imagine.

CTEs do **not** get materialised in advance into their own temporary table so what should the following return?

```
;WITH Hey (Name) 
AS 
(
...
)
SELECT name 
FROM Hey
JOIN some_other_table ON Name = name
```

If the Query Optimiser decided to use a nested loops plan and `Hey` as the driving table then presumably one insert would occur. However if it used `some_other_table`  as the driving table then the CTE would get evaluated as many times as there were rows in that other table and so multiple inserts would occur. Except if the Query Optimiser decided to add a spool to the plan and then it would only get evaluated once.

Presumably avoiding this sort of mess is the motivation for this restriction (as with the restrictions on side effects in functions)